# Makefile weird error

Tags: c++, c, makefile

This is my makefile and whenever I do make or make clean I get this error : 
"makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop."
I am pretty sure that I did it right, but not sure why this error is showing up. Its my first time dealing with this error so I have no clue how to fix it or go about it...

```
 COMPILER = gcc
 CCFLAGS = -g -Wall
 CFLAGS2 = -g

 all: malloc test

 debug:
make DEBUG=TRUE

 malloc.o: malloc.c malloc.h
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c malloc.c malloc.h

 malloc: malloc.o
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o malloc malloc.o

 test.o: test.c
$(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS2) -c test.c

 test: malloc.o test.o
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o test test.o malloc.o

 ifeq ($(DEBUG), TRUE)
  CCFLAGS += -g
 endif

 clean:
rm -f malloc
rm -f *.o
rm -f test
rm -f *.o



ERROR
  "makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop."
```

Comment: Indentation is crucual. Does this post reflect your Makefile accurately?

Comment: You know, if you search for "Makefile missing separator" in Google the entire first page of results will explain this error to you... it's probably the most common question ever asked about makefiles.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3):

Makefile requires you to have a tab character at the beginning of all the recipe lines.

```
 target ... : prerequisites ...
 <TAB>recipe
 <TAB>...
 <TAB>...
```

Comment: @ouah Thanks that worked fine!  I have another question. I have something called malloc.c in which I dont have a main function, basically my project was to implement malloc and I did so and malloc.c is just my implementation of malloc and my test.c is basically my main file where i do my testing. But I am gettign an error saying my malloc.c doesnt have a main.

Comment: @user3100209 you probably need to remove the line `malloc: malloc.o` and the line that follows in the Makefile.